# Gong WPF issue with ComboBox inside listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Hello I'm using [Gong WPF](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop) to reorder `Items` inside a ListBox

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxIssue.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBoxIssue"
    xmlns:dd="urn:gong-wpf-dragdrop"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<ListBox 
    dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
    dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UserControl1/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

GongWpf provide `AttachedProperties` to enable Drag and Drop within ListBox :

```
dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
```

The ListBox `ItemSource`is bound to an ObservableCollection of `Layer` in the main `ViewModel`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Layers = new ObservableCollection<Layer> { new Layer(), new Layer(), new Layer(), new Layer() };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Layer> Layers { get; }
}
```

For now Layer is just an empty Class used to show the problem :

```
public class Layer
{

}
```

The `UserControl` used as `DataTemplate` contains a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Height="25" Width="100">
    <ComboBoxItem>HELLO</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>BONJOUR</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>NIHAO</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Now when I reorder items using drag and drop within the `ListBox`, the dropped `ComboBox` `SelectedItem` is not visible anymore.

Why ?

Thanks

Comment: I have to re-set the selected item, the ItemsSource is fine. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Comment: ok see my update

Comment: Your issue is still not reproducible based on the information your have provided.

Comment: I tried to reorganise the question, basically SelectedItem is lost when ItemSource change, due to reordering.

Comment: I updated to the simplest example possible to show the issue I'm having. Definitely MCVE this time.

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: Thanks, but your example works for me if I use data-binding to bind the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox to a source property of Layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why ?

Because you haven't bound it to a source property of the `Layer` class. If you add such as property:

```
public class Layer
{
    private string _selectedItem;
    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set => _selectedItem = value;
    }
}
```

...and bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to it:

```
<ListBox 
    dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
    dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Height="25" Width="100" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                      xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                <s:String>HELLO</s:String>
                <s:String>BONJOUR</s:String>
                <s:String>NIHAO</s:String>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

...it works just fine for me.

Comment: ok so I should change my example again because my listbox itemsource is bound to a property... which I think is the problem when ItemSource change due to ViewModel reordering

Comment: As I have mentioned, you should provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable sample of your issue as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You asked why the selection was cleared and I have already given you the answer.

Comment: yes but this problem is within a bigger project and it is hard to find out where is the exact problem and how to extract the exact cause. So I'm trying my best to ask the perfect question.

Comment: Do you think it's easier for someone that doesn't even have access to the code and cannot reproduce the issue...?

Comment: No, that's why I keep trying to update and find the best way to explain the problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be very *minimal* to me.

Comment: No, that's why I keep trying to update and find the best way to explain the problem.

Comment: I accepted the answer, so you can sleep well tonight. Thanks anyway